# SQL Convert NVARCHAR to Datetime on Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have an SQL Function that retrieves data but I have a problem on the database, the one who handled it before made the field a NVARCHAR instead of DATETIME, so now I can't sort out the date or select the data between ranges.

Supposed I have a query:

```
Select order_confirmation.oc_number as oc,
order_confirmation.count as cnt,
order_confirmation.status as stat,
order_confirmation.po_number as pon,
order_summary.date_delivered as dd,
order_summary.delivery_quantity as dq,
order_summary.is_invoiced as iin,
order_summary.filename as fn,
order_summary.invoice_number as inum,
order_summary.oc_idfk as ocidfk,
order_summary.date_invoiced as di
FROM
order_confirmation,order_summary
where order_confirmation.id = order_summary.oc_idfk
order by order_summary.date_delivered DESC
```

I want to convert order_summary.date_delivered to a DATETIME format so that the ORDER BY statement would work properly. Please take note that I don't want to change the datatype permanently on the database structure, only in the query.I tried searching and trying other's solution but won't work plus I'm not yet familiar with SQL Server.

Thanks

Helpers:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use `convert(datetime, date_delivered, <type>)`.  Then fix your data to store date/time values using the proper type -- and that is not a string.

Comment: I got this, Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. I selected 110 as the type

Comment: Set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data and someone might be able to help you.  How do we know what your dates look like?

Comment: My dates looks like this 13-06-2013

Comment: The correct format is 105.

Comment: Same error in 105 sir

Answer (score 3):

on your order by clause use:

```
order by convert(datetime,order_summary.date_delivered, X)
```

where X=100,101,102... depending on the format you wish to have

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) you can see more details for convert function

Comment: I would suggest the CONVERT variant, as it provides the datetype. Cast won't convert to another date format.

Comment: I got this message. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: What data to you put into it. Is it a string? Maybe there are some missmatches due to wrong input.

Comment: The database field type is nvarchar so I believe it is a string, and on the database record, it is in this format, 13-06-2013 so I think that should work. But naa

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED** 
Based on Iconic's good point and to hopefully correct your overflow issue Use format 105 with your `CONVERT`

```
Select order_confirmation.oc_number as oc,
order_confirmation.count as cnt,
order_confirmation.status as stat,
order_confirmation.po_number as pon,
order_summary.date_delivered as dd,
order_summary.delivery_quantity as dq,
order_summary.is_invoiced as iin,
order_summary.filename as fn,
order_summary.invoice_number as inum,
order_summary.oc_idfk as ocidfk,
order_summary.date_invoiced as di
FROM
order_confirmation,order_summary
where order_confirmation.id = order_summary.oc_idfk
order by CONVERT(datetime, order_summary.date_delivered, 105) DESC
```

Comment: I would suggest the CONVERT variant, as it provides the datetype. Cast won't convert to another date format.

Comment: By datatype do you mean Format?  If so who cares what the format is when you're only using the field for a sort.

Comment: Tried also Sir. same error. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: That would indicate that you have something in `order_summary.date_delivered` that is not a string representation of a date

Comment: It's nvarchar and a sample date saved in my db, 13-06-2013

Comment: Well it cares in case of the 4/5/2015 or 5/4/2015? :D

Comment: I'm curious try....   `order by CONVERT(datatime, REPLACE(order_summary.date_delivered, '-','/'), 105) DESC`

Comment: Still not working, I've added screenshot to my question.

Comment: Well, then I still think you might have at least one row of data that is not a string representation of a date.   Try looking for characters that might not be a part of a date.  `Select date_delivered From order_summary where date_delivered Like '%[^0-9-]%'`

Comment: The query you gave doesn't show any results, so I believe that all date is properly formatted as string?